# HTML Email and Lotus Notes - Content is repeating

Tags: html, email, lotus-notes, email-client

I have an HTML Email campaign that I have tested with EmailOnAcid.com. The email displays fine in almost all clients except Lotus Notes v6.5, v7, v8 :(

In Lotus Notes 6.5 & 7, at the end of the email, Lotus seems to repeat the email from the start again, so it looks like the same email has been put in twice, but it hasn't.
Is there a mimimum height for HTML emails in Lotus? (height of my email is around 474px).
I have specified height on all image elements and on  tags.

In Lotus Notes 8, there is a minor problem; the lower part of the footer image repeats itself?

Does anyone have ideas as to what is causing these problems??

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Email</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="650" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td width="650">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="650">
                <tr>
                    <td width="650">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="650">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="650"><img src="http://www.website.com/images/hdr.jpg" width="650" height="36" border="0" alt="" style="display:block;margin:0;"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>            
                <tr>
                    <td width="650">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="650">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="137" height="53"><a href="http://www.website.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.website.com/images/hdr_left.gif" width="137" height="53" border="0" alt="" style="display:block;margin:0;"></a></td>
                                <td width="513" height="53"><img src="http://www.website.com/images/hdr_right.jpg" width="513" height="53" border="0" alt="" style="display:block;margin:0;"></td>                                
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="650">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="650">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="650"><img src="http://www.website.com/images/spacer_top.jpg" width="650" height="28" border="0" alt="" style="display:block;margin:0;"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="650">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="650">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="397" valign="top"><a href="http://www.website.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.website.com/images/gold_main.jpg" width="397" height="271" border="0" alt="" style="display:block;margin:0;"></a></td>                                
                                <td width="240" valign="top">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="240">                                  
                                        <tr>                                            
                                            <td><img src="http://www.website.com/images/title_text.gif" width="240" height="105" border="0" alt="" style="display:block;margin:0;"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>                                            
                                            <td><img src="http://www.website.com/images/spacer_white.gif" width="240" height="12" border="0" alt="" style="display:block;margin:0;"></td>
                                        </tr>                                                                            
                                        <tr>                                            
                                            <td><font style="font-family:verdana; font-size:10px;" color="#808180"><b>TEXT GOES HERE TEXT GOES HERE TEXT GOES HERE TEXT GOES HERE TEXT GOES HERE TEXT GOES HERE TEXT GOES HERE TEXT GOES HERE TEXT GOES HERE TEXT GOES HERE TEXT GOES HERE TEXT GOES HERE TEXT GOES HERE</b></font></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>                                            
                                            <td><img src="http://www.website.com/images/spacer_white.gif" width="240" height="12" border="0" alt="" style="display:block;margin:0;"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>                                            
                                            <td><font style="font-family:verdana; font-size:10px;" color="#808180"><b>TEXT GOES HERE TEXT GOES HERE TEXT GOES HERE TEXT GOES HERE TEXT GOES HERE TEXT GOES HERE TEXT GOES HERE TEXT GOES HERE</b></font></td>
                                        </tr>                                                                                
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td width="13"><img src="http://www.website.com/images/spacer_white.gif" width="13" height="2" border="0" alt="" style="display:block;margin:0;"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="650" height="12">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="650">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="650" height="85">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="397" height="85"><a href="http://website.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.website.com/images/ftr_left_cmras.jpg" width="397" height="85" border="0" alt="" style="display:block;margin:0;"></a></td>
                                <td width="253" height="85"><a href="http://website.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.website.com/images/ftr_right_lnk.gif" width="253" height="85" border="0" alt="" style="display:block;margin:0;"></a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears this might be an issue with the EmailsOnAcid testing system.